# Jquery hide & show to build quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

i'm trying to make a simple quiz using jquery hide & show functions , first i created some divs elements wich will be the questions + the last elements will contain a text & a button to watch result (there will be no result) ; i'm using two buttons : next & prev .

So the things i can't do on my own are :

1- hide the two buttons when they show the last div (Of the result !) ;

2-make the prev buttons stop on the first question .

3- how i can implement bootstrap radio options with Jquery to store answers & show them at the last on the click of button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="divs">
     <div class="cls1">1</div>
     <div class="cls2">2</div>
     <div class="cls3">3</div>
     <div class="cls4">4</div>
     <div class="cls5">5</div>
     <div class="cls6">6</div>
     <div class="cls7">7</div>
 </div>
 <a id="next">next</a>
 <a id="prev">prev</a>
```

Thanks in advance guys !

Comment: your snippet is not working here on stackoverflow. here's a fiddle of your code, for other users' sake: http://jsfiddle.net/wjq188tq/

Comment: thank you for adding this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidepastore/nrnq6meu/4/)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="divs">
     <div class="cls1">
       Gender<br/>
       <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
       <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
     </div>
     <div class="cls2">
       Language<br/>
       <input type="radio" name="language" value="java">Java<br>
       <input type="radio" name="language" value="python">Python
     </div>
     <div class="cls3">
        Preference<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="preference" value="morning">Morning<br>
        <input type="radio" name="preference" value="night">Night       
     </div>
     <div class="cls4">4</div>
     <div class="cls5">5</div>
     <div class="cls6">6</div>
     <div class="cls7">7</div>
     <div class="your-quiz-result"></div>
 </div>
 <a id="next">next</a>
 <a id="prev">prev</a>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs > div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0){
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();

            if($(".divs div:visible").next().length == 0){
                //1. Hide the two buttons
                $("#next, #prev").hide();

                //3. Show the results
                var divs = $(".divs div:visible").prevAll().clone();
                divs.show();

                //Reverse the order
                var divs = jQuery.makeArray(divs);
                divs.reverse();
                $(".your-quiz-result")
                    .empty()
                    .append(divs);
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0){
            console.log("There are still elements");
            $(".divs div:visible")
                .prev()
                .show()
                .next()
                .hide();
        }
        else {
            //2. Can't go previous first div
            console.log("Can't go previous first div");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you , it work as a charm ! i appreciate your help !

Comment: Hi  @SäLähÖßitø if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.